# How to display multiple markers on a google map using GeoFirestore (Java/Android)?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I am trying to add more than one marker on my map fragment using `GeoFirestore`, but I don't understand how to do so. I have tried to follow the guidance from their [site](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android), but I am still unable to get the desired results.

I have multiple documents in a collection that I wish to display on the map if they are within the desired range; however, I don't know where should I instantiate the markers.

Database structure in Firestore:

[image]

GeoFirebase Query Code:

```
if (distantCategoryValue != null) {
        switch (distantCategoryValue) {
            case "6 Km":

                CollectionReference geoFirestoreRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Events");
                GeoFirestore geoFirestore = new GeoFirestore(geoFirestoreRef);
                GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFirestore.queryAtLocation(new GeoPoint(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()), 6);
                geoQuery.addGeoQueryDataEventListener(new GeoQueryDataEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDocumentEntered(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, final GeoPoint geoPoint) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDocumentExited(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDocumentMoved(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, GeoPoint geoPoint) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDocumentChanged(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, GeoPoint geoPoint) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onGeoQueryReady() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onGeoQueryError(Exception e) {

                    }

                });

                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the first four overriding methods has as the first argument a `DocumentSnapshot` object that contains some data. Each method is called according to the operation that is taking place within a particular area. Now, to get that data, you ca use DocumentSnapshot's [getData()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getData()) method that has as a return type a `Map<String, Object>`. Simply iterate through the map and get the `l` property, which is an array that contains the latitude and longitude. Second approach would be to use DocumentSnapshot's [toObject(Class valueType)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#toObject(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) and convert each `DocumentSnapshot` object to an `Event` object. Once you got the data, add it to map using the following lines of code:

```
Event event = documentSnapshot.getValue(Event.class);
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(event.getLatitude(), event.getLongitude());
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
```

Comment: I also realize that I was adding the locations incorrectly, like so:  " geoFirestore.setLocation(userId, new GeoPoint(latitude, -longitude)". I took out the "-" in longitude and onDocumentEntered method started to work properly. Thank you so much!